# Finding the host name from a log file which is not separated by symbol using Java Regex

Tags: java

I have a log file and my task is to find the hostname of the log file which status is ERROR. Here are my log file details.

```
2017-02-09T02:37:44 [ERROR] Consumer iwjef99 could not be contacted
2017-02-09T02:37:46 [INFO] Message received from Producer w89fj93
2017-02-09T02:37:51 [ERROR] Consumer 7sjeuf returned 504
2017-02-09T02:37:53 [INFO] Message received from Producer a99jef9
2017-02-09T02:37:59 [INFO] Message sent to Consumer a99jef9
2017-02-09T02:38:55 [ERROR] Consumer a99jef9 disconnected unexpectedly
```

for the first log status is **ERROR** and hostname is **iwjef99**
.I already tried in this approach to find the hostname

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Arif\\Desktop\\test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Pattern e = Pattern.compile(".*\\bERROR\\b.*");
Pattern h1 = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]+|[0-9]+?[a-zA-Z]+)");
String st;
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = e.matcher(st);
    if (m.find()) {
        Matcher h = h1.matcher(st);
        if (h.find()) {
             list.add(h.group());
            }
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

It catching the string after "-" parameters and showing the output like this

```
09T
09T
09T
09T
```

But my desire output should like this

```
 
iwjef99
7sjeuf
a99jef9
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Okay why do you think It's outputting `09T` instead of `iwjef99` and why would the output be `iwjef99`/

Comment: When it trying to satisfy the second condition: "([a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]+|[0-9]+?[a-zA-Z]+)"  it finding the match where is a word containing number and character or not and every time it is true. But I can't find out how to escape it.

Comment: Your conditions don't include enough for the host name. Yours could be abc123 or 123abc but not a99jef9. I agree with the .split method for this since space is your delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern e = Pattern.compile(".*\\bERROR\\b.*");
```

I have modified this regex now it should be

```
Pattern e = Pattern.compile("\\[ERROR] [A-Za-z]+ ([\\w]+)");
```

I have removed your second regex so now your code looks like this

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File("logfile");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    Pattern e = Pattern.compile(".*\\[ERROR\\] [A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z0-9]+)");
    String st;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = e.matcher(st);
        if (m.find()) {
            list.add(m.group(1));

        }
    }
    for (String aList : list) {
        System.out.println(aList);
    }
```

Comment: Your second [] block is pretty much \w.

Comment: I don't want the whole string with ERROR rather than only the hostname. By the way, Thanks.

Comment: It's only the hostname.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't notice well. Thanks, Your solution seems best among them :)

Comment: Updated my regex, Thanks to @matt for suggesting \w :)

Comment: I also changed `\\]` to `]` since the `\\` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = st.split(" ");
if("[ERROR]".equals(tokens[1])){
    list.add(tokens[3]);
}
```

You should split by space and not use REGEX, you'll save yourself some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your regex, It's finding `09T` because it matches the regex, I've come up with the following regex that works which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928178/4417306):

---

```
([0-9]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-z]*
```

[working example](https://regex101.com/r/6RBHBb/1)

---

I've removed the `A-Z` part from that answer since the string you want to match appears to be lowercase only. The regex will match (from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928178/4417306)):

> - One or more numeric characters, followed by one or more alphabetic characters, followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters
>
> *or*
>
> - One or more alphabetic characters, followed by one or more numeric characters, followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters

Comment: Thanks a lot. That exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to match against one pattern, if the error log row always contains the word Consumer you can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[ERROR\\] Consumer ([\\w]*)");
```

and the server name can be found in group 1

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
if (m.find()) {
    String server = m.group(1);
}
```

If the first word after [ERROR] might vary

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[ERROR\\] ([\\w]*) ([\\w]*)");
```

then the second group contains the server

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
if (m.find()) {
    String server = m.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using regex, you can achieve your goal using String.Split() since the values appear in the same place when split by ' ' space character.

```
if (st.Split(' ')[1] == "[ERROR]") list.add(st.Split(' ')[3])
```

Comment: Souldn't you provide an answer?

Comment: if (st.Split(' ')[1] == "[ERROR]") list.add(st.Split(' ')[3])

Comment: I have provided a regex answer, Just incase the OP want's to use regex :)

Comment: String.split takes a String not a char, " instead of ' and  you shouldn't use == to compare strings, but .equals.